# ib i( i) builtin text object give confusing results (for empty blocks)

Tags: cursor-motions

When I use `vi(` (or `vib` or `vi)`) to select the inner-part of brackets, everything works fine whenever there is some content but as soon as the brackets are empty or contain only linebreaks, the *previous* bracket content is selected.

I would assume that the text-object should just fail (no selection) as it does when the cursor isn't between brackets.

**Question**: does this behavior seem normal to you or should I investigate more and possibly raise an issue on the [official repo](https://github.com/vim/vim) (and maybe try to fix it and create a pull request).

**Examples:**
In the following, cursor position is given by `{}` and highlighted text with `[...]`

```
(some text){(}) => vib => ([some text])()

(some text){(}  => vib => ([some text])(
)                         )
```

**Examples**: When the cursor is on the *closing* bracket of the empty field, the result is slightly different: only the last bracket is selected (nothing should be selected).

```
 (some text)({)} => vib => (some text)([)]

 (some text)(    => vib => (some text)(
{)}                       [)]
```

**Last Example** When several empty brackets are used, `vib` select the pair of *previous* brackets.

```
()(){(})  => vib => ()[()]()
```

**Edit**

I understand that selecting the inner part of a (mostly) void pair of bracket is useless, believe-me :)
The reason I stumbled upon this behavior is because I was writing a text-object script that relies on `ib` text-object and that was sometimes failing for this reason.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Could you tell us what is your question? Why do you want to select the content of a bracket pair that is empty? I suppose we need more context to give you a useful answer :-)

Comment: Note that you can't select 0 characters (the contents of `()`). I think `vab` would select the parens you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks! @VivianDeSmedt:  fair remark, I edited the question.

Comment: @Laurent may you should ask the question about the text object that you try to built. Some of the expert could have some suggestion about how to address your problem. Otherwise your question looks more like a "bug" report that should be posted to the Vim github (although I have some doubts that the behavior you have detected could be changed in a backward compatible way and be accepted as a bug :-|

Comment: Thanks, will do, sorry for the noise :)

Comment: Vim issue submitted here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/13514

Answer (score 1):

This has been improved/fixed in vim 9.1.0012

https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/3779516988f14f2070d827514c79383334a0946b

Comment: Indeed, thanks for reporting here. This is the result of the bug report I filed.

Comment: I know, this is just to make the question "complete".